# ¿Cómo genero un archivo excel en sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de generar un archivo Excel atraves de SQL server para crear un job que me envié esta data todos los días a un correo electrónico pero encontré un código para poder generarlo pero me dice SQL que ya es un proceso descontinuado.
Como es un forma mas actualizada para generarlo?

```
-- Crear una tabla temporal para almacenar los datos que se exportarán
CREATE TABLE #TempData (
Columna1 INT,
Columna2 VARCHAR(50),
-- Agrega más columnas según tu necesidad
);

-- Insertar datos en la tabla temporal
INSERT INTO #TempData (Columna1, Columna2)
 VALUES
(1, 'Dato1'),
(2, 'Dato2'),
-- Inserta más datos según tu necesidad;

 -- Definir la ruta del archivo Excel de destino
 DECLARE @ExcelFilePath NVARCHAR(255) = 'C:\Ruta\ArchivoExcel.xlsx';


 DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
 SET @SqlQuery = 
'SELECT Columna1, Columna2
 FROM #TempData
 ORDER BY Columna1';

--Este es el procedimiento para generar el excel pero ya esta descontinuado

EXEC sp_makewebtask
@outputfile = @ExcelFilePath,
@query = @SqlQuery,
@colheaders =1,
@FixedFont=0,@lastupdated=0,@resultstitle='Query Result';


DROP TABLE #TempData;
```

Comment: Las recomendaciones parecen ser el uso de SSRS. Pero eso trae más retos que tendrías que enfrentar y sería demasiado extenso el explicarlo en una respuesta de este sitio. En general, no hay soluciones directas porque ese no es el objetivo de SQL Server y lo mejor es utilizar herramientas especializadas en eso.